# javascript query selector and const issue

Tags: javascript

hope you can clarify an issue I am having that is driving me crazy:

I am trying to get te value of the inpt "#size" in JS, I am using the comand:

```
submit.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#size').value;
  document.querySelector('#size').value = '';
})
```

it works like this, but the thing is that i can not declare the variables to make my code shorter and to handle the data latter, if I use:

```
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');//refers to the button to activate the event listener

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#size').value;
  document.querySelector('#size').value = '';
})
```

it does not get any value from the `size`, console says:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'submit' has already been declared
```

it is an error that is happening often and I still not able to solve, hope some of you guys an clarify what am I doing wrong.

EDIT:html code below:

````
<body>

  <input type="text" id="size">
  <button id="submit">Sumbit</button>
  <ul id="output">

  </ul>


    <script src="functtions.js"></script>
</body>```

thanks
````

Comment: It sounds like you declared another variable named `submit` up above - can you post a [MCVE] showing the problem? (though either way, this sounds off-topic)

Comment: show your html please

Comment: ```<body>

  <input type="text" id="size">
  <button id="submit">Sumbit</button>
  <ul id="output">
    
  </ul>


    <script src="functtions.js"></script>
</body>```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have another variable called submit somewhere else. Using function usually prevent such variable collision problem, so what about this kind of code?

```
function () {
    let submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
    let size = document.querySelector('#size');
    let output = document.querySelector('#output');

    submit.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        output.innerHTML = size.value;
        size.value = '';
    });
}();
```

Comment: ```function add() {
  let submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
  let size = document.querySelector('#size');
  let output = document.querySelector('#output');

  submit.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      output.innerHTML = size.value;
      size.value = '';
  });
}

add();```, like it is working, it is very strange because there were not any other variables with the same name on the document, all the rest of the code was comented, it works declaring the variables in the function scope, thank you!, i will keep it in mind in case it happens in the future